# Cannot import caffe2 from caffe2.python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, caffe

I'm trying to install caffe2 on macbook pro. I followed the official instructions:
https://caffe2.ai/docs/getting-started.html?platform=mac&configuration=compile#python-configuration

I built it from source successfully, but when I try the command:

```
~/anaconda2/bin/python -c 'from caffe2.python import core' 2>/dev/null & echo "Success" | echo "Failure"
```

It says：

```
Failure
'~/anaconda2/bin/python -c 'from…' has ended
```

I have no idea what is wrong with it.
My computer has two different versions of python. The default one is python 2.7.10 in the directory '/usr/bin/python'.  Another one is python 2.7.13 in the directory '~/anaconda2/bin'. I do not know which one it use. With the command:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DUSE_CUDA=OFF ..
sudo make install
```

I installed it successfully. I also setup the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable `export PYTHONPATH="~/anaconda2/bin/"` in `~/.bash_profile` and execute the command:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libpython2.7.dylib ~/anaconda2/lib/libpython2.7.dylib /usr/local/caffe2/python/caffe2_pybind11_state.so
```

Everything is OK until now. But when I execute:

```
~/anaconda2/bin/python -c 'from caffe2.python import core' 2>/dev/null & echo "Success" | echo "Failure"
```

It show "Failure", I also tried:

```
python -c 'from caffe2.python import core' 2>/dev/null & echo "Success" | echo "Failure"
```

and it did not work. What should I do?

Comment: are you running the command in the same directory you installed it(caffe root folder)?

Comment: I went down this path and ended up using the Docker container: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/docker

Answer (score -2):

in `conda/build.sh` replace `BLAS=MKL` with `BLAS=Eigen`

```
CMAKE_ARGS+=("-DBLAS=MKL") # gives unresolved dnnBatchNormalizationCreateForward_v2_F32
CMAKE_ARGS+=("-DMKL_INCLUDE_DIR=$CONDA_PREFIX/include")
CMAKE_ARGS+=("-DBLAS=Eigen")
```

in `conda/meta.yaml` comment out references to MKL build:

```
# - mkl-include
# - mkl
```

run:

```
# - mkl-include
# - mkl
```